# how to get Response time when I ues resttemplate

Tags: java, rest, tcp, resttemplate

this is my code,but i know it's not accurate because it called function,so how can i get the accurate response time which consists of tcp handshack,transfer time and so on .thank you very much.

```java
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(endTime-startTime+"ms");
```

Comment: Maybe you can use Spring Boot Actuator to get the detail information.

Comment: use AOP e.g. interceptor (PerformanceMonitorInterceptor )